# How to prevent ActiveMQ CPP send method from blocking forever?

Tags: c++, activemq-cpp

I am developing a software that uses `ActiveMQ` C++ library. The problem that I have is, when I try to send a message and the network is down, the **send** method (method of `cms::MessageProducer` class) blocks forever and I need to recover the control in this case.

I am using persistent deliver mode (It is compulsory, I can't avoid it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you set the *sendTimeout* when you create `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`? It is set to 0 by default, which means "infinite".

```
auto_ptr<ActiveMQConnectionFactory> connectionFactory(
     new ActiveMQConnectionFactory( brokerURI ) );
connectionFactory->setSendTimeout( 1000 ); // number of milliseconds
// ...
// creating Session and MessageProducer as usually
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you gave me a good hint. Actually I'm using a cms::ConnectionFactory not a ActiveMQConnectionFactory. I don't know wich are the difference between this two classes. By the way, do you know a good tutorial about ActiveMQ for cpp ?

Comment: @CMorgan cms::ConnectionFactory is an abstract class, you surely use ActiveMQConnectionFactory accessing it through cms::ConnectionFactory (it is an interface in java JMS API, this translates to an abstract C++ class). For a tutorial, check how JMS works in Java (CMS seems to model it quite the same way), and download the ActiveMQ C++ library source and see the "examples" dir. Oh, BTW, don't forget to accept the answer if it's working for you.